# Define a function that contains an unknown function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i was asked to define a function reduce, that has three parameters, an array, an unknown function, and a number, and reduces the array into a number

and this is was i was given before i was asked to define the function

```
reduce([1, 2, 3], function(total, number) {

    return total + number;

}, 0); // should return 6
```

I am a bit clueless on what this is asking me to do to be completely honest

if i could at least get some guideline id be grateful

here is my attempt

```
var reduce = function(array, func, initial){ 

    function func(){
}

    for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

        func(initial, array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code a little better :)

Comment: sounds like you're being asked to create [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function reduce(list, f, acc) {
    return list.length ?
        reduce(list.slice(1), f, f(acc, list[0])) :
        acc;
}
```

Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure to create a total variable which will be redefined after every function call. You were very close. Try this out:

```
var reduce = function(array, func, initial){
    var total = initial,
        arr_len = array.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr_len; i++){
        total = func(total, array[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: ha, i think this is what the question was aiming towards. i guess i did not realize how to formulate an unknown function to be called each time. in the exemplary expression above, is total+number representing the parameter function?

Comment: Yes. The function takes the current state, `total`, and changes that state with the current argument of the array (`number` above). The function you used just increments `total`.